# case statement depending on day of week within where clause

Tags: sql, select, case

I am trying to write a case statement within my where clause. Below is my query. I want to execute the query based on the weekday. Basically if its monday it needs to be datecreated = getdate()-3 
if its tuesday it needs to be a range datecreated between getdate()-3 and getdate()-1 
if its wed-friday then it needs to be datecreated = getdate()-1

```
 SELECT Count(dispute_reference_no)AS reg_inc 
 FROM   mytable 
 WHERE  reasoncd IN ('b2', 'b3') 
 AND    datecreated = ( 
        CASE 
           WHEN Datename(weekday,Getdate()) = 'Monday' THEN dbo.Fn_getdateonly(Getdate()-3))
           WHEN datename(weekday,getdate()) = 'tuesday' THEN (dbo.fn_getdateonly(getdate()-3) 
 AND    dbo.fn_getdateonly(getdate())) 
 ELSE dbo.fn_getdateonly(getdate()-1) 
END)
```

the above code is not working. It wont let me add a range within case statement.

Comment: very hard to know what you want, but your parenthesis are on wrong places

Comment: Correct way of using `CASE` is `CASE 
      WHEN ...
      WHEN ...
   END ` Your END isn't related to `Case`

Comment: Forget the error. Wha you mean `need to be a range datecreated`  You can't create a range on a `CASE` and compare with a single value

Comment: ok so if the week day is tuesday then I need to say datecreated between getdate()-3 and getdate()-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically rewrite your `where` clause like this, but you could get the desired behavior by using a series of logical operators:

```
SELECT COUNT(Dispute_Reference_no) AS reg_inc
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  reasoncd in ('b2', 'b3') AND
       ((DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'monday' AND 
         datecreated = dbo.fn_getdateonly(GETDATE()-3)) OR
        (DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) = 'tuesday' AND 
         datecreated BETWEEN dbo.fn_getdateonly(GETDATE()-3) AND 
                             dbo.fn_getdateonly(GETDATE())) OR
        (atecreated = dbo.fn_getdateonly(GETDATE()-1)
       )
```